# GRASS 7.1 (dev.) i.landsat.toar error

Tags: grass-gis

I am working with Landsat 8 image acquired in 2014. I am trying to convert the raw image (DN) to Top Of Atmosphere Reflectance/Radiance (i.landsat.toar) in Grass 7.1 (still under development). The reason for using this version is that it is caters for landsat 8. I specify the metadata file and load the information etc. I get the same error every time:

> ERROR: Unable to open header file for raster map

- Base Name of input raster band: LC81700832014160LGN00_B1@PERMANENT
- Prefix for output raster maps: LC81700832014160LGN00_B1.toar
- Name of metadata file: C:\Users\carinswart\Documents\GIS_DataBase\Landsat8\GHT\09June14\LC81700832014160LGN00_MTL.txt

I have tried to be careful not to leave gaps in my file names.

Comment: Can you give more details??? eg. what parameters do you have??? sometimes grass is strict and you have to be careful with names.

Comment: Base Name of input raster band: LC81700832014160LGN00_B1@PERMANENT

Comment: prefix for output raster map: LC81700832014160LGN00_B1.toar                           Name of landsat metadata file:C:\Users\carinswart\Documents\GIS_DataBase\Landsat8\GHT\09June14\LC81700832014160LGN00_MTL.txt

Answer (score 6):

I think that for the input file you don't use the number of band. Your input must be LC81700832014160LGN00_B  and then the channel number automatically filled. You can try this.

```bash
i.landsat.toar input=LC81700832014160LGN00_B output=output. metfile=LC81700832014160LGN00_MTL.txt
```