# i.landsat.toar not working and returning error

Tags: raster, grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat-8

First time using grass. I need to convert DN to reflectance. Imagery -> Sat. images tools-> i.landsat.toar. But when I add raster name. I get error. 
Im using **landsat 8** images

```
WARNING: WARNING: ESUN evaluated from REFLECTANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND
Calculating...
ERROR: Unable to open header file for raster map <LC81890272015184LGN00_B11@abcdefgh1@
```

I have try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135982/grass-7-1-dev-i-landsat-toar-error?rq=1) but it wasnt working.

Comment: Pls add the exact `i.landsat.toar` command from the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to call the file without the band number.

Here is an example how it work after you [downloaded](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) and extracted the **Landset 8** scene as *Level 1 GeoTIFF Data Product*:

1. Change into the dir where you extracted the files and execute the following command:

```cmd
cd "C:\Users\wittich\test"
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B1.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.1 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B2.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.2 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B3.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.3 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B4.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.4 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B5.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.5 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B6.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.6 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B7.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.7 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B8.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.8 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B9.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.9 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B10.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.10 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_B11.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.11 --o
r.in.gdal input=LC81950252015306LGN00_BQA.TIF output=LC81950252015306LGN00.QA --o
```

2. run the satellite images tool with the base name (no number behind the dot!):

```cmd
i.landsat.toar input=LC81950252015306LGN00. output=test. metfile=LC81950252015306LGN00_MTL.txt --o
```

for further details check the manual of **[`i.landsat.toar`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Semi automatic classification plugin (pre-processing )  a plugin in QGIS 2.10.1.

I have worked with it using Landsat 7 ETM+ images. Landsat 8 should not be any different
[image]